# app do not connect to web service using wifi but other apps works fine

Tags: android, android-wifi

Please check this logcate. I have connected to wifi works fine with other app installed in my android phone,
But my app can not connect to web services it shows error in catlog mentioned in below.
I have set permissions :

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>`

Here is the logcat:

```
03-09 21:29:01.634: E/WifiStateMachine(630): WiFiStateMachine SCAN ALARM
03-09 21:29:01.636: E/WifiStateMachine(630):  ConnectedState (when=-1ms what=131143 arg1=-2 arg2=-2) !CMD_START_SCAN -2 -2 ic=32 proc(ms):1 dur:334 rssi=-40 f=2462 sc=60 link=65 tx=0.0, 0.0, 0.0  rx=0.0 list=2462 [on:0 tx:0 rx:0 period:1193] from screen [on:0 period:1545228292]
03-09 21:29:01.637: E/WifiStateMachine(630):  L2ConnectedState (when=-3ms what=131143 arg1=-2 arg2=-2) !CMD_START_SCAN -2 -2 ic=32 proc(ms):3 dur:334 rssi=-40 f=2462 sc=60 link=65 tx=0.0, 0.0, 0.0  rx=0.0 list=2462 [on:0 tx:0 rx:0 period:1] from screen [on:0 period:1545228293]
03-09 21:29:01.638: E/WifiStateMachine(630): WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source -2 txSuccessRate=0.00 rxSuccessRate=0.00 targetRoamBSSID=any RSSI=-40
03-09 21:29:01.638: E/WifiStateMachine(630): WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN with age=80460 interval=227812 maxinterval=300000
03-09 21:29:01.638: E/WifiStateMachine(630): WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN full=false
03-09 21:29:01.638: E/WifiConfigStore(630): makeChannelList age=3600000 for "customsoft2"WPA_PSK max=6 bssids=1
03-09 21:29:01.638: E/WifiConfigStore(630): has 88:53:95:28:9a:f9 freq=2462 age=1199 ?=true
03-09 21:29:01.638: E/WifiStateMachine(630): WifiStateMachine starting scan for "customsoft2"WPA_PSK with 2462
03-09 21:29:01.638: E/WifiStateMachine(630): stopReconnectWifi Wfd=false StopScan=false mDontReconnectAndScan=false
03-09 21:29:01.640: E/WifiStateMachine(630): [1,457,539,141,639 ms] noteScanstart no scan source
03-09 21:29:01.641: E/WifiMonitor(630): handleEvent unknown: 15  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
03-09 21:29:01.671: E/MPlugin(1622): Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
03-09 21:29:01.807: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630): TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 33 num clients 8
03-09 21:29:01.807: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630):  packet count Tx=209 Rx=256
03-09 21:29:01.987: E/WifiStateMachine(630):  ConnectedState (when=-1ms what=147461!SCAN_RESULTS_EVENT 0 0 found=4 known=2 got=4 bcn=0
03-09 21:29:01.988: E/WifiStateMachine(630):  L2ConnectedState (when=-2ms what=147461!SCAN_RESULTS_EVENT 0 0 found=4 known=2 got=4 bcn=0
03-09 21:29:01.989: E/WifiStateMachine(630):  ConnectModeState (when=-2ms what=147461!SCAN_RESULTS_EVENT 0 0 found=4 known=2 got=4 bcn=0
03-09 21:29:01.989: E/WifiStateMachine(630):  DriverStartedState (when=-3ms what=147461!SCAN_RESULTS_EVENT 0 0 found=4 known=2 got=4 bcn=0
03-09 21:29:01.990: E/WifiStateMachine(630):  SupplicantStartedState (when=-3ms what=147461!SCAN_RESULTS_EVENT 0 0 found=4 known=2 got=4 bcn=0
03-09 21:29:01.990: E/WifiStateMachine(630): [1,457,539,141,990 ms] noteScanEnd no scan source
03-09 21:29:01.994: E/WifiStateMachine(630): wifi setScanResults statecom.android.server.wifi.WifiStateMachine$ConnectedState@39784b18 sup_state=COMPLETED debouncing=false
03-09 21:29:01.994: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateSavedNetworkHistory(): SSID mismatch "customsoft"WPA_PSK SSID="customsoft" "customsoft2"
03-09 21:29:01.994: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateSavedNetworkHistory(): SSID mismatch "customsoft2's Mac mini"WPA_PSK SSID="customsoft2's Mac mini" "customsoft2"
03-09 21:29:01.995: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateSavedNetworkHistory(): try "customsoft2"WPA_PSK SSID="customsoft2" customsoft2 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS] ajst=0
03-09 21:29:01.995: E/WifiConfigStore(630): linkConfiguration try to link due to DBDC BSSID match "customsoft" and "customsoft2" bssida 88:53:95:28:9a:f9 bssidb 88:53:95:28:8c:31
03-09 21:29:01.995: E/WifiConfigStore(630):         got known scan result 88:53:95:28:9a:f9 key : "customsoft2"WPA_PSK num: 1 rssi=-43 freq=2462
03-09 21:29:01.995: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateSavedNetworkHistory(): try "customsoft"WPA_PSK SSID="customsoft" customsoft [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS] ajst=128
03-09 21:29:01.995: E/WifiConfigStore(630): linkConfiguration try to link due to DBDC BSSID match "customsoft2" and "customsoft" bssida 88:53:95:28:8c:31 bssidb 88:53:95:28:9a:f9
03-09 21:29:01.995: E/WifiConfigStore(630):         got known scan result 88:53:95:28:8c:31 key : "customsoft"WPA_PSK num: 1 rssi=-54 freq=2462
03-09 21:29:01.995: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateSavedNetworkHistory(): SSID mismatch "customsoft2's Mac mini"WPA_PSK SSID="customsoft2's Mac mini" "customsoft"
03-09 21:29:01.995: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateSavedNetworkHistory(): SSID mismatch "customsoft2"WPA_PSK SSID="customsoft2" "customsoft"
03-09 21:29:01.996: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateSavedNetworkHistory(): SSID mismatch "customsoft"WPA_PSK SSID="customsoft" "Joispot-wifi"
03-09 21:29:01.996: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateSavedNetworkHistory(): SSID mismatch "customsoft2's Mac mini"WPA_PSK SSID="customsoft2's Mac mini" "Joispot-wifi"
03-09 21:29:01.996: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateSavedNetworkHistory(): SSID mismatch "customsoft2"WPA_PSK SSID="customsoft2" "Joispot-wifi"
03-09 21:29:01.996: E/WifiConfigStore(630): associateWithConfiguration(): try "Joispot-wifi"
03-09 21:29:01.996: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateSavedNetworkHistory(): SSID mismatch "customsoft"WPA_PSK SSID="customsoft" "Nanostuffs-Hathway"
03-09 21:29:01.996: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateSavedNetworkHistory(): SSID mismatch "customsoft2's Mac mini"WPA_PSK SSID="customsoft2's Mac mini" "Nanostuffs-Hathway"
03-09 21:29:01.996: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateSavedNetworkHistory(): SSID mismatch "customsoft2"WPA_PSK SSID="customsoft2" "Nanostuffs-Hathway"
03-09 21:29:01.996: E/WifiConfigStore(630): associateWithConfiguration(): try "Nanostuffs-Hathway"-WPA_PSK
03-09 21:29:01.997: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateSavedNetworkHistory(): SSID mismatch "customsoft"WPA_PSK SSID="customsoft" "ICAI"
03-09 21:29:01.997: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateSavedNetworkHistory(): SSID mismatch "customsoft2's Mac mini"WPA_PSK SSID="customsoft2's Mac mini" "ICAI"
03-09 21:29:01.997: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateSavedNetworkHistory(): SSID mismatch "customsoft2"WPA_PSK SSID="customsoft2" "ICAI"
03-09 21:29:01.997: E/WifiConfigStore(630): associateWithConfiguration(): try "ICAI"-WPA_PSK
03-09 21:29:01.999: E/WifiConfigStore(630):  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false
03-09 21:29:02.808: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630): TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 33 num clients 8
03-09 21:29:02.810: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630):  packet count Tx=209 Rx=256
03-09 21:29:03.444: E/WifiStateMachine(630):  ConnectedState (when=-2ms what=131155 arg1=3!CMD_RSSI_POLL 3 0 "customsoft2" 88:53:95:28:9a:f9 rssi=-40 f=2462 sc=60 link=65 tx=0.0, 0.0, 0.0  rx=0.0 bcn=0 [on:0 tx:0 rx:0 period:1804] from screen [on:0 period:1545230100] gl hn u24 rssi=-35 ag=0 hr ticks 0,0,0 ls-=0 [56,56,56,56,61] brc=0 lrc=0
03-09 21:29:03.445: E/WifiStateMachine(630):  L2ConnectedState (when=-4ms what=131155 arg1=3!CMD_RSSI_POLL 3 0 "customsoft2" 88:53:95:28:9a:f9 rssi=-40 f=2462 sc=60 link=65 tx=0.0, 0.0, 0.0  rx=0.0 bcn=0 [on:0 tx:0 rx:0 period:1] from screen [on:0 period:1545230101] gl hn u24 rssi=-35 ag=0 hr ticks 0,0,0 ls-=0 [56,56,56,56,61] brc=0 lrc=0
03-09 21:29:03.445: E/WifiStateMachine(630):  get link layer stats 0
03-09 21:29:03.468: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateConfiguration freq=2462 BSSID=88:53:95:28:9a:f9 RSSI=-41 "customsoft2"WPA_PSK
03-09 21:29:03.809: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630): TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 33 num clients 8
03-09 21:29:03.811: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630):  packet count Tx=209 Rx=256
03-09 21:29:04.812: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630): TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 33 num clients 8
03-09 21:29:04.813: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630):  packet count Tx=209 Rx=256
03-09 21:29:05.815: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630): TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 33 num clients 8
03-09 21:29:05.817: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630):  packet count Tx=209 Rx=256
03-09 21:29:06.474: E/WifiStateMachine(630):  ConnectedState (when=-4ms what=131155 arg1=3!CMD_RSSI_POLL 3 0 "customsoft2" 88:53:95:28:9a:f9 rssi=-40 f=2462 sc=60 link=65 tx=0.0, 0.0, 0.0  rx=0.0 bcn=0 [on:0 tx:0 rx:0 period:3002] from screen [on:0 period:1545233130] gl hn u24 rssi=-35 ag=0 hr ticks 0,0,0 ls-=0 [56,56,56,56,61] brc=0 lrc=0
03-09 21:29:06.478: E/WifiStateMachine(630):  L2ConnectedState (when=-8ms what=131155 arg1=3!CMD_RSSI_POLL 3 0 "customsoft2" 88:53:95:28:9a:f9 rssi=-40 f=2462 sc=60 link=65 tx=0.0, 0.0, 0.0  rx=0.0 bcn=0 [on:0 tx:0 rx:0 period:4] from screen [on:0 period:1545233134] gl hn u24 rssi=-35 ag=0 hr ticks 0,0,0 ls-=0 [56,56,56,56,61] brc=0 lrc=0
03-09 21:29:06.479: E/WifiStateMachine(630):  get link layer stats 0
03-09 21:29:06.505: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateConfiguration freq=2462 BSSID=88:53:95:28:9a:f9 RSSI=-40 "customsoft2"WPA_PSK
03-09 21:29:06.818: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630): TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 33 num clients 8
03-09 21:29:06.821: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630):  packet count Tx=209 Rx=256
03-09 21:29:07.823: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630): TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 33 num clients 8
03-09 21:29:07.827: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630):  packet count Tx=209 Rx=256
03-09 21:29:08.830: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630): TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 33 num clients 8
03-09 21:29:08.833: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630):  packet count Tx=209 Rx=256
03-09 21:29:09.512: E/WifiStateMachine(630):  ConnectedState (when=-3ms what=131155 arg1=3!CMD_RSSI_POLL 3 0 "customsoft2" 88:53:95:28:9a:f9 rssi=-40 f=2462 sc=60 link=65 tx=0.0, 0.0, 0.0  rx=0.0 bcn=0 [on:0 tx:0 rx:0 period:2980] from screen [on:0 period:1545236168] gl hn u24 rssi=-35 ag=0 hr ticks 0,0,0 ls-=0 [56,56,56,56,61] brc=0 lrc=0
03-09 21:29:09.515: E/WifiStateMachine(630):  L2ConnectedState (when=-6ms what=131155 arg1=3!CMD_RSSI_POLL 3 0 "customsoft2" 88:53:95:28:9a:f9 rssi=-40 f=2462 sc=60 link=65 tx=0.0, 0.0, 0.0  rx=0.0 bcn=0 [on:0 tx:0 rx:0 period:3] from screen [on:0 period:1545236171] gl hn u24 rssi=-35 ag=0 hr ticks 0,0,0 ls-=0 [56,56,56,56,61] brc=0 lrc=0
03-09 21:29:09.517: E/WifiStateMachine(630):  get link layer stats 0
03-09 21:29:09.544: E/WifiConfigStore(630): updateConfiguration freq=2462 BSSID=88:53:95:28:9a:f9 RSSI=-40 "customsoft2"WPA_PSK
03-09 21:29:09.833: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630): TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 33 num clients 8
03-09 21:29:09.836: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630):  packet count Tx=209 Rx=256
03-09 21:29:10.838: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630): TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 33 num clients 8
03-09 21:29:10.841: E/WifiTrafficPoller(630):  packet count Tx=209 Rx=256
```

Here is the code:

```
public class JSONParser {

private InputStream is = null;
private JSONObject jObj = null;
private String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {


    try {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        // execute HTTP post request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();


            is = resEntity.getContent();



    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

Comment: Please also add your code snippet

Comment: It is started when app launch. I have start service(remote) at very begining. Everytime catlog get filled by this error

Comment: You are not serious. What has this log to do with a webservice? You should post the code that provokes these error messages.

Comment: Thank you greenapps, This error is not only for app, It shows continouslly after app stopped as well as uninstall. I have changed 2 mobile 1. intex aqua speed 2. lenovo ... Both have same problem

Comment: Please remove that irrelevant log. Then explain what not works exactly. Post the error logs that your app produces only.